# Apache2 - setting PERL5LIB via SetEnv under CGI

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, perl, cgi, setenv

my setup is as follows: I have one Apache2 webserver running different vhosts, one vhost is for the production website, the other vhost is for a staging / preview system. Both vhosts have different DocumentRoots and also different (Perl) CGI folders. The used modules for each of these vhosts should be in different directories, so I did the following:

```
<VirtualHost...>
ServerName production
SetEnv PERL5LIB /home/production/modules
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost...>
ServerName staging
SetEnv PERL5LIB /home/staging/modules
</VirtualHost>
```

However, I just noticed that in my Perl CGI scripts, both paths get filled into my @INC, so I can not separate the staging modules from the production modules, e.g. the SetEnv directive is not limited to a single virtual host, but seems to work globally.

How can I solve this?

Thanks!
Jonas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found something called [SetEnvIf](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_setenvif.html) which can be used to set environment variables based on the request headers.
eg.

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "\request-for-staging\" PERL5LIB=/home/staging/modules
```

But that maybe too heavy...so you could try [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html)'s [E=...] option.

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 2):

```
  <VirtualHost ...>
      ServerName dev1
      PerlOptions +Parent
      PerlSwitches -I/home/dev1/lib/perl
  </VirtualHost>

  <VirtualHost ...>
      ServerName dev2
      PerlOptions +Parent
      PerlSwitches -I/home/dev2/lib/perl
  </VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Good idea, but I think this only works if you're running mod_perl.  I'm not, and when I tried this I got a syntax error.